# What are the associations of the word "Heights" in a city name?

Tags: proper-nouns, geography, toponyms

There are lots of cities and other designations with the word "Heights" in the name. Does this refer to something specific? Is it a marketing tactic perhaps?

Examples:

- Hacienda Heights
- Sterling Heights
- Washington Heights
- Golan Heights

Comment: General Reference. It just means that relative to the surrounding area, these places are built on ***higher** ground*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think it has a deeper social meaning than simply altitude.

Comment: @mgb: Sure - in just the same way that [the folks who live on the hill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Folks_Who_Live_On_the_Hill) are generally assumed to be "socially higher up / richer" as well as happening to live at a higher altitude. But that's all trivial metaphoric extension. You can see the opposite influence in references to *valley girls*, say, in California or Wales.

Comment: Whoever thought this question was GR is surely from one of those *Heights*. Might better start a campaign for Hyper-ELU for the hyperknowing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the 19th century most big cities weren't particularly pleasant places. Horses, coal fires and limited sanitation meant they were dirty and smelly.
The best places to live was on a hill in the fresh clean air - so XXX heights was the upper class area of the city. Or later, a marketing slogan for a new area to give the impression of luxury

Golan heights is a high plateau on the Israel/Syria border with rather more strategic than real estate value.

Comment: Thanks! That's basically what I had assumed, but could find virtually nothing about it searching the internet. I also seem to have the impression that it refers to a poorer area, but that might just stem from a couple coincidental examples.

Comment: As the answer says, when they were built they would often have been the better areas, but these things go in cycles: as an area expands, the better class areas often gradually become poorer areas, until they get regenerated as better areas again. So whether a particular area is currently better or poorer may depend on nothing more than where in the cycle it is.

Comment: Or, the word is simply meant to [_invoke_](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy-ab&q=%22heights+trailer+park%22&oq=%22heights+trailer+park%22&gs_l=hp.3..0i22i30l4.1443.6645.0.7427.22.22.0.0.0.0.230.3124.0j21j1.22.0...0.0...1c.1.16.psy-ab.L_3C6aVQwL4&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47534661,d.aWc&fp=6f6c554fe2a39046&biw=1186&bih=810) an aura of upscale living.

Comment: @robamaton - there are probably some deprived housing projects called something-heights, just because the planners went through a list of names and had already used -lakes/groves/mews/park etc